# Powershell job not working when run as schedule task

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

We have a powershell script which extracts email attachments saving them to a local folder.  This functions fine when run from powershell but when called from Windows Task Scheduler the job reports as Running and never downloads any files.  Looking in task manager the powershell.exe is running under the correct service account which has admin permissions on the server.  Analyze wait chain reports that Powershell is waiting for OUTLOOK.exe.

```
Add-Type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook"

#Setting up Correct mailbox

$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$ns = $Outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
$folder = $ns.CreateRecipient('name@domain.com')

#Getting today's date
$date = Get-Date -Format MM/dd/yyyy

#For each message in the shared mailbox
foreach ($message in $ns.GetSharedDefaultFolder($folder, 6).Items) 
{
   write-host $message.Subject

   #For each attachment in the messages
   foreach ($att in $message.Attachments){
   #If the attachment is .csv, .txt or .xlsx and received on today's date
   if (($att.FileName -like "*.csv*" -or $att.FileName -like "*.txt*" -or $att.FileName -like "*.xlsx*") -and ($message.ReceivedTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") = $date))
   {
       write-host "Attachment: " $att.filename
       #save the file
       $att.saveasfile( (Join-Path "C:\EmailPull\Email Files" $att.FileName ))
   }
   }
}

Write-Output "Done"
```

We have run the scheduled task as a bat file call which then called powershell and the script.  The Batch file runs as expected but not when called from the task scheduler.  We have run the task calling Powershell and then the file as an argument.
Outlook is running on the server under the same service account which is calling the powershell and the service account has domain admin permissions.

Comment: Running Office applications via Windows services is not officially supported - see [this Microsoft support article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office). The workaround in [this superuser.com answer](https://superuser.com/a/655458/139307) _may_ be effective.

Comment: Thanks, tried the posted suggestion that didn't work, so scheduled through SQL Agent and worked as expected.

Comment: Glad to hear it. I encourage you to post your solution as an answer (you'll be able to self-accept it after 48 hours), along with additional background information, if you have it.