# Read Outlook mailbox through a SQL Server job via Powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have a PowerShell script which I can run on my own computer and it runs just perfectly. It basically just search's my mailbox for a certain subject and then download any attachment from that mail. I am running into an issue now when I am trying setting it up as a SQL Server Agent job. I am running it on a proxy account of my own details, it says it is running successfully when I trigger the job but its not downloading the latest file, Possible the proxy doesn't have permission to access the mailbox but unsure if this is the cause. Any suggestions would be great. I'll attach the PowerShell script below but it does run on my own computer so don't believe this is wrong.

```
# Required COM object for interacting with Outlook
Add-Type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook"

# Path to the folder where attachments will be saved
$saveFolder = "\\SQLPWP00013\Dataupload"

# Subject of the email to filter
$targetSubject = "*CBP v's DBP_Part*"

# Create an Outlook application object
$outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application

# Get the MAPI namespace
$namespace = $outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

# Get the target mailbox
$mailbox = $namespace.Folders | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "tom.forde@outlook.com" }

# Get the Inbox folder of the target mailbox
$inbox = $mailbox.Folders.Item("Inbox")

# Get the most recent email in the Inbox folder with the target subject
$email = $inbox.Items |
    Where-Object { $_.Subject -like $targetSubject } |
    Sort-Object CreationTime -Descending |
    Select-Object -First 1

# Check if a matching email was found
if ($email) {
    # Check if the email has attachments
    if ($email.Attachments.Count -gt 0) {
        # Iterate through each attachment in the email
        foreach ($attachment in $email.Attachments) {
            # Save the attachment to the specified folder
            $attachment.SaveAsFile("$saveFolder\$($attachment.FileName.Replace("'", ''))")
            Write-Host "Attachment saved: $($attachment.FileName)"
        }
    } else {
        Write-Host "The email does not have any attachments."
    }
} else {
    Write-Host "No email with the specified subject found in the tom.forde@.com mailbox Inbox."
}

# Release the COM objects
if ($attachment) {
    [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($attachment) | Out-Null
}
if ($email) {
    [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($email) | Out-Null
}
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($inbox) | Out-Null
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($mailbox) | Out-Null
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($namespace) | Out-Null
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($outlook) | Out-Null
```

Comment: You need to add logging to the script to ascertain exactly where the issue is. Is it line 1 or is it line 100? There should be output from the script appearing in the SQL Agent logs

Comment: Looking at the second line: Do you have Outlook Client installed on the SQL Server?

Comment: I have looked into it but cant seem to determine if Outlook Client is installed. Would this be a default one or one which would of been specially installed.

Comment: Agent jobs are typically executing in a context equivalent to `runas /noprofile` as well, so they won't have access to the account's registry hive nor any settings contained within it. This would probably include any authentication tokens you might have saved while running Outlook in the account's desktop environment.

Comment: To Access Outlook you need to use credentials.   The following example uses Login to use the credentials : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/pia/how-to-get-and-log-on-to-an-instance-of-outlook

Comment: In most cases Office Interop doesn't work in unattended scenario's (this is a recurring issue here on SO when people try to run Office Interop from task scheduler), although using a SQL agent should work. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75148108/powershell-job-not-working-when-run-as-schedule-task for more info about this subject. If you are using Exchange, use either EWS (for on prem) or MS Graph (when using Exchange Online) as an alternative, it's also much faster and uses way less resources compare to Office Interop.

Comment: You really need to look at your logs there should be something obvious there saying it can't access outlook client.